# Watermark in LibreOffice writer 5.1.6.2

Tags: libreoffice

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS using LibreOffice Writer 5.1.6.2
I want to insert a watermark "Draft" on a document. I browse the net and several forums, and all say I have to go to Format > Page > Background. Point is that I don't have a "background" tab in Page. I am a bit lost. 
Also shall the watermark be an image or can I type in text like "draft", "Confidential", etc...
Can anybody help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Graham's answer, which directly answers the OP's question in LO 5.1, another option is to upgrade to LibreOffice 6.0 because it has a watermark option at Format -> Watermark.  It appears to be limited to text, however.

[image: Menu in LibreOffice 6.0 showing Format->Watermark]

[image: Watermark Dialog Box in LibreOffice 6.0]

Answer (score 0):

In LibreOffice Write 5.1.6.2 go to Format > Page > Area > Fill > and select Bitmap from the dropdown selection. Click on Import Graphic and select an already saved graphic with the text you want to have as a watermark. As an example, I found "SAMPLE" as an image using Google and then saved it to my local drive but you could equally well find a graphic for "DRAFT" OR "CONFIDENTIAL" or a logo as required.

[image]

Results in:

[image]